# Will AWS Firehose batch records using `FirehoseClient.putRecord()`?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

The javadoc for `FirehoseClient.putRecord()` warns that Firehose buffers records before delivering them to the destination, and that consequently it may be necessary to insert newline characters into the data to "disambiguate the data blobs".

I plan to use Firehose to write json objects to S3, by calling `FirehoseClient.putRecord()` (many times) with single json objects. I will **not** use `FirehoseClient.putRecordBatch()` at all.

What will be written to S3? Will I get one S3 object per json object? Or is it possible that several json objects might be concatenated into a single S3 object?